# Disable body scroll when mobile nav is open in Next.js

Tags: javascript, dom, next.js

Typically you could toggle a class or overflow property on the body element to disable scroll when a mobile menu or modal is open, but with Next.js being rendered server side, there's no access to the document object. How could I achieve disabling body scroll while the mobile nav menu is open in Next.js?

I tried accessing the document object to toggle overlay hidden but because Next.js is rendered server side, the document object is not available yet.

I also tried using state and passing it into the nav component to toggle the styles, but useState cannot be used at the top level of the app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the proper way to do it, but I used a useEffect hook to ensure the code is only run after the component is loaded and then set mobile menu state as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  mobileNav
    ? (document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden')
    : (document.body.style.overflow = 'auto');
}, [mobileMenuState]);
```